# Google Chart not loading in IE (but loads when in Incognito Mode)

Tags: internet-explorer, google-visualization

We have a website which has a Google Chart in its homepage: www.globalforcestn.com

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. But in IE (IE 11, specifically), the chart won't load. It loads, though, when I set my IE to InPrivate browsing.

I've been looking for a solution for days now but still I can't resolve it. :(

Hoping for your tips. Thanks!

Comment: Check if IE is not running in compatabillity-mode. Seems like it.

Comment: Yes, it is not running in compatibility mode. The problem with compatibility mode is that it makes the layout of the site even worse. And it didn't make the Google Chart appear either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can view the page (using IE11) without any problems.
I checked, when putting IE-mode to IE9 it didn't work.

On IE:

-Press F12

-Select the desctop icon (bottom left)

-Set mode to Edge

Use this to force edge mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

IN your script.js I found this error-line (106)

```
for (k = 0; k < s.rules.length; k++) {
```

It states that acces is denied but it keeps running (maby this is the solution)

Comment: Hello. Did you see the chart in the homepage when you checked it on IE 11? I already did that meta tag suggestion before but it didn't do any difference to the site when viewed in IE. I placed it inside the <head> tag.

Comment: On default settings I could see (and use) the chart. It also worked in IE 10 modes.

IE 9 was a problem

Comment: are you sure? mine is the exact opposite. there is no chart in IE 11 (Windows 8). But when I viewed it on IE 9 (Windows 7), the chart showed up. It's really weird.

Comment: Added a bit in the awnser (last 3 lines)

Comment: I saw that error before but afterwards, it would no longer show up. This is really a weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem when I realized that in 2 computers with the same version of IE11, in one of them it showed google chart and not in the other one.

The only difference was the date and time on Windows. I fixed the date from the computer with wrong date to the current date... and problem solved!